# Application Insights sql dependency error on History_GetTaskStateById

Tags: sql-database

When looking into application insights a see most of the errors coming from:

`SQL: [xdb_processing_tasks].[History_GetTaskStateById]`

Returning error 50000 running Sitecore 9.0.2. The stored procedure only checks some records and I don't see any exceptions in the logs.

How can I solve this issue or should this dependency be excluded?

Comment: Is there a message with that error code? Maybe check the `sysmessages` table: `SELECT * FROM sysmessages WHERE error = 50000` - with just the error code, its impossible to see what your issue might be.

Comment: Nothing in there, but if I run the stored procedure with an invalid guid, I'll get:
`Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xdb_processing_tasks.History_GetTaskStateById, Line 77 [Batch Start Line 0]
A rebuild process with the specified unique identifier does not exist.`

Comment: @Luuk did you resolve this issue? I am seeing the same errors in my application insights logs.

Comment: @bmyers I don't see them anymore, maybe because we've upgraded to the latest Application Insights.